# OnClick is not working, but no errors appear in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I am currently learning React, I am creating a joke generator. I created a local file and was able to pull the data (jokes) and display it on the browser. Now, I am trying to create a button that when you click, it displays a random joke. I can see the joke and button, but no action is being triggered. I check the console and there are no errors.  If I use `onClick = {randomJoke}`, then I get an error saying listener was expecting a function, not an object. Can someone point help me out and point out what is wrong?

**This is how I currently have it set up:**

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.getRandomJoke = this.getRandomJoke.bind(this);
    }

    getRandomJoke(){
       return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]

    }

    render() {
        const randomJoke =  this.getRandomJoke()
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
             <p> {randomJoke.question}</p>
            <p>{randomJoke.answer}</p>

        <button onClick={this.getRandomJoke}>
           click here
        </button>
        </React.Fragment>
        )
        }
    }
          export default SportsJokesApi;
```

**This is how the file was originally scripted prior to adding the button.**

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

    getRandomJoke(){
       return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]

    }

    render() {
        const randomJoke =  this.getRandomJoke()
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <p>{randomJoke.question}</p>
            <h1>{randomJoke.answer}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>           
        )
        }
    }
          export default SportsJokesApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just `return` a new component on `onClick` event. You need to set some state first. This guide is useful: https://flaviocopes.com/react-show-different-component-on-click/

Answer (score 0):

You need to ***re-render*** your React component, when there is a new joke. To do this store the `randomJoke` in the `state` of your React Component.

When you call `this.getRandomJoke` you should update the `state` along with it, so that a re-render of the React component is triggered. When this happens the UI will be updated with the latest value of the `randomJoke`

```js
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from './SportsJokesData';

const initialState = {
  randomJoke: null
};

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRandomJoke = this.getRandomJoke.bind(this);
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  getRandomJoke() {
    this.setState({
      randomJoke: SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { randomJoke } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment >
      <p> {randomJoke.question} </p> 
      <p> {randomJoke.answer} </p>
      <button onClick = {this.getRandomJoke}>click here </button> 
      </React.Fragment >
    );
  }
}
export default SportsJokesApi;
```